# How to use SQL Server 2008 Database project in installation time

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have created SQL Server 2008 Database project using visual studio 2010. after build and deploy this project i saw dbschema file that contain SQL queries that i use to create my database inside the XML tags. And there is another .sql file(This file also contain that sql queries. but there is no XML tags)

In this 2 files i want to know what is the file that i can use to create database in installation time and how to execute that file in installation time. 
I found some details from   http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2010/05/02/vs-2010-database-project-an-introduction.aspx

Hope you guys can help me to get some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy the database project you just need to .dbschema file. 
If your database is composed of multiple .dbschema then you have to deploy using the manifest.

The tool you need is vsdbcmd.exe in VS 2010. It works with SQL 2008. It does not work in SQL 2012.

Check out the following link on how to do it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193283.aspx